# How to have a Custom Container's text in the Header

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I am trying to build a custom container.  I have created a separate object for my header and set User.msvStructureType = "Heading"

I'd expect that when selecting the container, any text I type will be in the header but that's not the case.

The text is showing up centered in the container.

How can I have my container behave like the built in containers, when you select the container and type any text it is automatically placed into the header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom container is a group shape, and your header is a sub-shape of the group.
Select your group shape, then, on the Developer tab, click Shape Design \ Behavior, then ensure that Edit text of group is unticked.